# how to use innerJoinWith() in series connection

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to join 4 tables one after another. For this, I am currently trying below code

```
->innerJoinWith('Districts',function($q){
                return $q->innerJoinWith('Blocks',function($q){
                    return $q->innerJoinWith('Divisions',function($q){
                        return $q->innerJoinWith('Villages');
                    });
                });
            });
```

how can I summarize in a single line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the relations in CakePHP, https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html here you can have more details about them,

ones you have established a relation all you have to do is use "contain" in your query and all the required data will be fetched.

you can find more about contain here : https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

Comment: if still there is a problem, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Note that, while containment will often work, there are situations where explicit joins are still required.